# SML, unbound variable or constructor

Tags: sml

This is my code, and it keeps giving me unbound error message.

[image]

I'm actually really new to SML. so, i really dont know how to fix it.

It seems like using a and b is bad thing.

I tried to declare `a` and `b`

like this

```
a : int;
b : int;
```

but still doesn't work.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Please post your code rather than linking to it.

Comment: Please don't post, or link to, pictures of text. Our ancestors gave us copy and paste. Learn how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a syntax problem. All your code is missing is a `|` to separate the clauses of `calculate`. Just add one at the beginning of lines 5-8.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the missing `|`s between function clauses that Andreas mentions, you cannot apply the `+`, `-`, `*` and `div` operators to values of type *calctree*. You need to reduce each `a` and `b` to integers using your function first. For example,

```
datatype ops = PLUS | MINUS | TIMES | DIV
datatype calctree = LEAF of int | CALC of ops * calctree * calctree

fun getOp PLUS = op +
  | getOp MINUS = op -
  | getOp TIMES = op *
  | getOp DIV = op div

fun calc (LEAF x) = x
  | calc (CALC (oper, a, b)) = getOp oper (calc a, calc b)
```